# My Groups OG Setup

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am not able to list My Groups for the authenticated users. so when they login and click on My Groups, they should see only those groups created by them. I am using D7 with OG and VIEW to create the My Group page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the url **yoursite.com/user-groups**.

This URL is created by View and it will return the group of the user who is logged in.

The reason that you are not getting is probably you are misssing panel and page manager module. Enable them and try again.

Comment: When i do so, it says Myname Groups andbelow that is written, User is not a member of any group. But i want to list down the Groups which i created as a normal authenticated user.